# What is the relation between the 3 triangles and the whole triangle?

Tags: geometry

There is a question in my lecture note.

Call the area of a whole arbitrary triangle A, and the three areas of the corner triangles $a_1, a_2 , $ and  $a_3$, respectively.

Then what is the relation between A, $a_1$, $a_2$,and $a_3$ ?

I guess that the relation can be proved by trigonometric functions, but there are too many variables to handle.

[image]

Comment: Are $D$, $E$, and $F$ midpoints of the sides?

Comment: How are the corner triangles defined (i.e. the points D, E and F)?

Comment: No...there is no restriction on the sides.  And the corner triangles are not be conditioned.

Comment: If there are no conditions on the corner triangles I’m not sure what you’re hoping for.. area $a_1$ can approach the area of the larger triangle.

Comment: I  read the material again, and it is  about  Gauss and Monge formula.I found some paper [link](http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jgg/jgg12/j12h2pech.pdf) and I guess the relation of these triangles should be similar like the pentagon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems three areas $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are not enough to construct a Monge type formula.
The three areas satisfies an inequality rather an identity.

To avoid confusion, we will use $\Delta$ instead of  "A"  to denote the area of $\triangle ABC$. We are going to show the areas satisfies following inequality.

$$\sqrt{\Delta}(\Delta - a_1 - a_2 - a_3) \ge 2\sqrt{a_1a_2a_3}$$

In fact, this is a necessary and sufficient condition for $a_1, a_2, a_3$ to be realized as the area of such sub-triangles.

---

Introduce parameters $u,v,w \in (0,1)$ so that the barycentric coordinates of $D, E, F$ wrt $\triangle ABC$ are

$$D : (1-u,u,0),\quad F : (0,1-v,v)\quad\text{ and }\quad E : ( w, 0, 1-w )$$
In terms of $u,v, w$, we have

$$a_1 = \Delta u(1-w),\quad a_2 = \Delta v(1-u) \quad\text{ and }\quad a_3 = \Delta w(1-v)$$

This leads to following inequality on the areas
$$\begin{align} \sqrt{\Delta}(\Delta - a_1 - a_2 - a_3)
= &\;\Delta^{3/2}(1 - u - v - w + uv+vw + wu)\\
= &\;\Delta^{3/2}((1-u)(1-v)(1-w) + uvw)\\
\color{blue}{{\rm AM} \ge {\rm GM} \rightarrow }\quad \ge &\;
 2\Delta^{3/2}\sqrt{(1-u)(1-v)(1-w)uvw}\\
= &\; 2\sqrt{a_1a_2a_3}\end{align}\tag{*1}$$

One the other direction. let's say we are given three numbers $a'_1, a'_2, a'_3 \in (0,\Delta)$ which satisfy $(*1)$. Define $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3 \in (0,1)$ by setting $\alpha_k = \frac{a'_k}{\Delta}$. Let

$$K_{\pm}(p,q,r) = (1 - p - q - r)
\pm \sqrt{ (1 - p - q - r)^2 - 4pqr}$$

Using $(*1)$, it is easy to verify both $K_{\pm}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ are non-negative. Define 
$$U_{\pm}(p,q,r) = \frac{K_{\pm}(p,q,r) + 2p}{2(1-r)}$$
and set

$$(u,v,w)_{\pm} = (U_{\pm}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3), U_{\pm}(\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_1), U_{\pm}(\alpha_3,\alpha_1,\alpha_2))$$

For both choice of sign of $\pm$, we have $u_{\pm},v_{\pm},w_{\pm} \ge 0$. With help of a CAS, one can verify they satisfy

$$u_{\pm}(1-w_{\pm}) = \alpha_1,\quad
v_{\pm}(1-u_{\pm}) = \alpha_2\quad\text{ and }\quad
w_{\pm}(1-v_{\pm}) = \alpha_3$$
This implies $u_{\pm},v_{\pm},w_{\pm} \in (0,1)$. Using these as barycentric coordinates, we can find $D,F,E$ on $AB, BC, CA$ to make corresponding area metaches: i.e. $a_1 = a_1'$, $a_2 = a_2'$ and $a_3 = a_3'$.